# Will the moderator who has been deleting my comments kindly contact me?

Tags: discussion, bug, deleted-comments

On my comment on an answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6887), I received a reply yesterday which apparently indicated that the responder didn't understand that the comment was intended to be humorous.

So I replied, with a comment to the effect: "That's the joke".

I later received a reply to my comment, and on viewing it, realised that my response had been deleted.

So I replied, noting that my earlier comment had been deleted.

Now I find that my subsequent reply has been deleted, too (as has the responder's second response - but **not** his first).

What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just so everyone knows what we're talking about, here's the full list of comments from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6890/31394):

> Was it Garthe who had the singing career? – Mark Bannister Nov 14 '11 at 11:04
>
> @MarkBannister, no, why would you assume that? Garthe was always a criminal and stayed in African prison until he escaped to America. – user2513149 yesterday
>
> @user2513149 - related: knowyourmeme.com/memes/thats-the-joke – Mark Bannister 23 hours ago
>
> @MarkBannister, that's off-topic. – user2513149 23 hours ago
>
> @user2513149: No, it really wasn't. I don't know who deleted the comment, though. – Mark Bannister 16 hours ago

Your second and third comments were both flagged as "no longer needed", and were deleted by the moderator (not me) who handled those flags. user2513149 self-deleted their second comment.

I've now deleted the two remaining comments, as they don't seem to add anything useful to the answer: a six-year-old joke which wasn't especially popular (the comment has a score of 1), isn't a constructive comment on the answer, and is evidently causing confusion doesn't need to stay.

Comment: I can understand deleting the whole thread (for the reasons you gave), but I'm baffled as to why my replies to user2513149 were deleted as "no longer needed", given that it left his question without an answer.

Comment: @MarkBannister: You were replying to a comment, not a question.  Comments are not important and don't get to stick around if they're not doing anything useful *for the question or its answers*.  (Of course, we also know that the user you were replying to had read your comment, so *they* certainly didn't need your reply to stick around.)

Comment: @Kevin: How do you know that the user had read my comments? If the user had read my comments, why wasn't his comment also deleted?

Comment: @MarkBannister They responded to your second comment by saying `that's off-topic`, so they must have seen it. Not deleting their (unflagged) comment was an oversight on the part of the mod who deleted your (flagged) comment - it was clearly obsolete after your comment was gone.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Was it user2513149 who flagged my comments as "no longer needed"? If so, everything seems a lot clearer, although some sort of notification of what was happening would have been helpful.